# Print page from hidden iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem hiding the page I want to print.

When I click on the input button :

```
<input type="submit" id="print" name="print">
```

This executes the following :

```
$(function(){
   $('#print').click(function(){
       if($('#bills_ID').val()==''){popUpMessage(Error);}
       else { window.open('Bills/BillsPrint.php?bills_ID='+$('#bills_ID').val(), '_blank') } 
   }); 
});
```

and prints the page. At this point I do not want to open this page Bills/BillsPrint.php when printing. I simply want it print without displaying the page.

how can i try this by using hidden ifram

Comment: possible duplicate of [hide print page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799972/hide-print-page)

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the hidden `iframe` like this:

```
<iframe src="" style="display: none" id="myPrintView"></iframe>
```

And use jQuery as follows:

```
$('#print').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#bills_ID').val()=='')
    {
        popUpMessage(Error);
    }
    else
    { 
        $('#myPrintView').attr('src', 'Bills/BillsPrint.php?bills_ID='+$('#bills_ID').val()); 
        $('#myPrintView').get(0).contentWindow.print();
    } 
});
```

You can see a working [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/TTUQY/).